# webview+ jsoup on all pages

Tags: android, webview, jsoup

I would like to use parse jsoup to all html pages, which are load in my webview. I know, hot it doing with my first, start page. 
 For example, user see main page,which consist only news, after jsoup parser.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private WebView webView;
    Button btnback ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btnback = (Button) findViewById(R.id.backbutton);
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView_act_viewer);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setInitialScale(100);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
        View.OnClickListener oclBtnBack = new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public   void   onClick (View v){
                webView.goBack();
            }
        };
         btnback.setOnClickListener(oclBtnBack);
        new LoadData().execute();

    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed (){
        if(webView.canGoBack()) webView.goBack();
        else super.onBackPressed();
    }
    private class  LoadData extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>
    {
        String html=new String();
        Document doc = null;
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            try {

                doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.fly4free.pl/").timeout(100000).get();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Elements alldivs=doc.select("div.entry");
            html=alldivs.html();
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

            super.onPostExecute(result);
            webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null,html,
                    "text/html", "utf-8", null);

        }
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.my, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: I am sorry but it is unclear what you are asking :)

Comment: For start url i need use this construction
Elements alldivs=doc.select("div.entry");
but for other links need 
Elements alldivs=doc.select("div.article__content");